# VNC Access for multiple simultaneous users?

Tags: vnc

Is there a good tutorial to set up an Ubuntu 18 or 20 server in the AWS EC2 environment with vnc access for multiple users at the same time?

I’d like anywhere from 1 - 10 people to have their own basic desktop for web access, Python work, etc.

I know how to set it up for one user. It’s the multiple setup I need help with.